# JAXB Marshalling a List of List of Maps

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

Folks,

I'm new to to world of using JAXB for marshalling and unmarshalling objects.

I am trying to marshal an object that can be best said to be a list of list of maps.

The final outcome I'm trying to get to is as given below:

```
<parametricSearchResult>
   <allFilters>
      <name>custom_year</name>
      <name>abcd</name>
   </allFilters>
   <allFields>
      <field>
         <name>custom_year</name>
         <value count="10">2012</value>
         <value count="8">2011</value>
      </field>
      <field>
         <name>abcd</name>
         <value count="8">2011</value>
      </field>
   </allFields>
</parametricSearchResult>
```

With the code that I have written, I get this as the output

```
<parametricSearchResult>
    <allFilters>
        <name>custom_year</name>
        <name>abcd</name>
    </allFilters>
    <allFields>
        <allFilters>
            <mName>test</mName>
            <field>
                <value count="10">
                    <mValue>2012</mValue>
                </value>
                <value count="8">
                    <mValue>2011</mValue>
                </value>
            </field>
            <name>test</name>
        </allFilters>
        <allFilters>
            <mName>test</mName>
            <field>
                <value count="4">
                    <mValue>2011</mValue>
                </value>
            </field>
            <name>test</name>
        </allFilters>
    </allFields>
</parametricSearchResult>
```

The code that I have is given below

**ParametricSearchResult**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "parametricSearchResult")
public class ParametricSearchResult {

    private final List<String> mFilterFields = new ArrayList<String>();

    private final List<Map<String, Integer>> mFiltersToCountsMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();

    public void setFilterFields(List<String> fields) {
        mFilterFields.addAll(fields);
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "allFilters")
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public List<String> getFilterFields() {
        return mFilterFields;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "allFields")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JAXBParametricSearchResultSerializer.class)
    public List<Map<String, Integer>> getValuesAndCounts() {
        return mFiltersToCountsMap;
    }

    public void addFilterFieldsAndCounts(final String field, final String filterValue, final Integer count) {
        final int index = mFilterFields.indexOf(field.toLowerCase());
        if (index == -1) {
            mFilterFields.add(field.toLowerCase());
            HashMap<String, Integer> mapValuesToCounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            mapValuesToCounts.put(filterValue.toLowerCase(), Integer.valueOf(count));
            mFiltersToCountsMap.add(mapValuesToCounts);
        } else {
            Map<String, Integer> mapValuesToCounts = mFiltersToCountsMap.get(index);
            mapValuesToCounts.put(filterValue.toLowerCase(), Integer.valueOf(count));
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getFilterValueToCountMap(String filterName) {
        final int index = mFilterFields.indexOf(filterName.toLowerCase());
        if (index == -1) {
            return new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        } else {
            return mFiltersToCountsMap.get(index);
        }
    }   
}
```

**ParametricSearchResultType**

```
public class ParametricSearchResultType {

    private final List<ParametricFilterType> allFilters = new ArrayList<ParametricFilterType>();

    @XmlElement
    public List<ParametricFilterType> getFilters() {
        return allFilters;
    }

    public void setFilter(final ParametricFilterType data) {
        allFilters.add(data);
    }
}
```

**ParametricFilterType**

```
public class ParametricFilterType {

    private String mName = "";

    private final List<ParametricMapEntryType> mFilterAllEntries = new ArrayList<ParametricMapEntryType>();

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(final String data) {
        mName = data;
    }

    public void setAllFilters(final ParametricMapEntryType data) {
        mFilterAllEntries.add(data);
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "field")
    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    public final List<ParametricMapEntryType> getAllFilterEntries() {
        return mFilterAllEntries;
    }
}
```

**ParametricMapEntryType**

```
public class ParametricMapEntryType {

    @XmlValue
    public String mValue;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "count")
    public Integer mCount;

}
```

**JAXBParametricSearchResultSerializer**

```
public class JAXBParametricSearchResultSerializer extends XmlAdapter<ParametricSearchResultType, List<Map<String, Integer>>> {

    @Override
    public ParametricSearchResultType marshal(final List<Map<String, Integer>> data) throws Exception {
        ParametricSearchResultType result = new ParametricSearchResultType();
        for (Map<String, Integer> aMap : data) {
            ParametricFilterType filters = new ParametricFilterType();
            filters.mName = "test";
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> anEntry : aMap.entrySet()) {
                ParametricMapEntryType entry = new ParametricMapEntryType();
                entry.mValue = anEntry.getKey();
                entry.mCount = anEntry.getValue();
                filters.mFilterAllEntries.add(entry);
            }
            result.allFilters.add(filters);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, Integer>> unmarshal(final ParametricSearchResultType data) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**ParametricSearchResultTester**

```
public class ParametricSearchResultTester {

    ParametricSearchResult mResult;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Throwable {

        mResult = new ParametricSearchResult();
        mResult.addFilterFieldsAndCounts("CUSTOM_YEAR", "2012", 10);
        mResult.addFilterFieldsAndCounts("CUSTOM_YEAR", "2011", 8);
        mResult.addFilterFieldsAndCounts("ABCD", "2011", 4);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Throwable {
        mResult = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testThatMarshallingWorks() throws Throwable {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ParametricSearchResult.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(mResult, System.out);
    }
}
```

After reading more documentation made some changes to the code and after making those changes, I ended up with this as the output

```
<parametricSearchResult>
    <allFilters>
        <name>custom_year</name>
        <name>abcd</name>
    </allFilters>
    <allFields>
        <filters>
            <field>
                <value count="10">2012</value>
                <value count="8">2011</value>
            </field>
            <name>test</name>
        </filters>
        <filters>
            <field>
                <value count="4">2011</value>
            </field>
            <name>test</name>
        </filters>
    </allFields>
</parametricSearchResult>
```

Almost there but still needs some more cleanup and rearranging of the elements. Not sure what else to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I can't give you the very expected answer without any deep understanding of your requirements, business, and so on.

Here comes my pseudo try.

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder = {"filterNames", "fields"})
public class ParametricSearchResult {


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    @XmlType(propOrder = {"name", "values"})
    public static class Field {


        public static Field newInstance(final String name,
                                        final Value... values) {

            final Field instance = new Field();

            instance.setName(name);

            for (Value value : values) {
                instance.getValues().add(value);
            }

            return instance;
        }


        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
        public static class Value {


            public static Value newInstance(final int count,
                                            final String value) {

                final Value instance = new Value();

                instance.setCount(count);
                instance.setValue(value);

                return instance;
            }


            public int getCount() {
                return count;
            }


            public void setCount(final int count) {
                this.count = count;
            }


            public String getValue() {
                return value;
            }


            public void setValue(final String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }


            @XmlAttribute(required = true)
            private int count;


            @XmlValue
            private String value;


        }


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }


        public void setName(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        public Collection<Value> getValues() {

            if (values == null) {
                values = new ArrayList<Value>();
            }

            return values;
        }


        @XmlElement(required = true)
        private String name;


        @XmlElement(name = "value")
        private Collection<Value> values;


    }


    public static void main(final String[] args)
        throws JAXBException, IOException {

        final ParametricSearchResult result = new ParametricSearchResult();

        result.getFilterNames().add("custom_year");
        result.getFilterNames().add("abcd");

        result.getFields().add(
            Field.newInstance(
            "custom_year",
            Value.newInstance(10, "2012"),
            Value.newInstance(8, "2011")));

        result.getFields().add(
            Field.newInstance(
            "abcd",
            Value.newInstance(8, "2011")));

        final JAXBContext context =
            JAXBContext.newInstance(ParametricSearchResult.class);

        final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        marshaller.marshal(result, System.out);

        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");

        context.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {


            @Override
            public Result createOutput(final String namespaceUri,
                                       final String suggestedFileName)
                throws IOException {

                return new StreamResult(System.out) {


                    @Override
                    public String getSystemId() {
                        return "noid";
                    }


                };
            }


        });
    }


    public Collection<String> getFilterNames() {

        if (filterNames == null) {
            filterNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        return filterNames;
    }


    public Collection<Field> getFields() {

        if (fields == null) {
            fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
        }

        return fields;
    }


    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "allFilters", nillable = true, required = true)
    private Collection<String> filterNames;


    @XmlElement(name = "field")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "allFields", nillable = true, required = true)
    private Collection<Field> fields;


}
```

prints

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parametricSearchResult>
    <allFilters>
        <name>custom_year</name>
        <name>abcd</name>
    </allFilters>
    <allFields>
        <field>
            <name>custom_year</name>
            <value count="10">2012</value>
            <value count="8">2011</value>
        </field>
        <field>
            <name>abcd</name>
            <value count="8">2011</value>
        </field>
    </allFields>
</parametricSearchResult>
```

and here comes the XML Schema.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="parametricSearchResult" type="parametricSearchResult"/>

  <xs:complexType name="parametricSearchResult">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="allFilters" nillable="true">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="allFields" nillable="true">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="field" type="field" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="field">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="value" type="value" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="value">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="count" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

JAXB is not good at dealing with Map, hence the need for an adapter. Basically, most map adapters transform maps into list of entries. Once you have a good adapter, you could have an object extending List>, then that object could be included into a List itself.

You'll probably be able to have your XML look exactly like you want it to be with more fiddling, but this solution will not be portable when the types used to instantiate the generics differ.

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

After dwelling on this for a while, I reworked the way I was trying to create the different objects.

This is what I did to solve my quandry. I created three new classes as given below. After doing some more reading this is what I came up with.

**ParametricSingleFilterMapEntry**

```
public class ParametricSingleFilterMapEntry {

    private String mValue;

    private Integer mCount;

    public void setValue(final String data) {
        mValue = data;
    }

    @XmlValue
    public String getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    public void setCount(final Integer count) {
        mCount = count;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "count")
    public Integer getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }
}
```

The next class that contains a list of ParametricSingleFilterMapEntry

**ParametricSingleFilterAllEntries**

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {"fieldName", "allEntriesForSingleField"})
public class ParametricSingleFilterAllEntries {

    private String mFilterField;

    private final List<ParametricSingleFilterMapEntry> mAllEntriesForSingleField = new ArrayList<ParametricSingleFilterMapEntry>();

    public void setField(final String name) {
        mFilterField = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getFieldName() {
       return mFilterField;
    }

    public void setAllMapEntries(final List<ParametricSingleFilterMapEntry> data) {
        mAllEntriesForSingleField.addAll(data);
    }

    public void setAMapEntry(final ParametricSingleFilterMapEntry entry) {
        mAllEntriesForSingleField.add(entry);
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    public List<ParametricSingleFilterMapEntry> getAllEntriesForSingleField() {
        return mAllEntriesForSingleField;
    }    
}
```

And the final class that ties the above two classes in nicely

**ParametricSearchResult**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "parametricSearchResult")
public class ParametricSearchResult {

    private final List<ParametricSingleFilterAllEntries> mAllFilterEntries = new ArrayList<ParametricSingleFilterAllEntries>();

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "allFields")
    @XmlElement(name = "field")
    public List<ParametricSingleFilterAllEntries> getAllFilterEntries() {
        return mAllFilterEntries;
    }

    public void addEntry(final ParametricSingleFilterAllEntries entry) {
        mAllFilterEntries.add(entry);
    }

    public void addEntries(final List<ParametricSingleFilterAllEntries> entries) {
        mAllFilterEntries.addAll(entries);
    }

    public void addEntry(final String filterName, final String filterValue, final Integer count) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filterName)) {
            ParametricSingleFilterMapEntry newMapEntry = new ParametricSingleFilterMapEntry();
            newMapEntry.setValue(filterValue);
            newMapEntry.setCount(count);
            if (mAllFilterEntries.isEmpty()) {
                ParametricSingleFilterAllEntries newFilterEntry = new ParametricSingleFilterAllEntries();
                newFilterEntry.setField(filterName);
                newFilterEntry.setAMapEntry(newMapEntry);                
                addEntry(newFilterEntry);
                return;
            } else {
                ParametricSingleFilterAllEntries newFilterEntry = new ParametricSingleFilterAllEntries();
                for (ParametricSingleFilterAllEntries entry : mAllFilterEntries) {
                    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(entry.getFieldName())) {
                        if (entry.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase(filterName)) {
                            entry.setAMapEntr(newMapEntry);                            
                            return;
                        } else {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                newFilterEntry.setField(filterName);
                newFilterEntry.setAMapEntry(newMapEntry);                        
                addEntry(newFilterEntry);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this approach helps somebody else who might face a similar issue.